# Why rendererForOverlay for MapKit is not called?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, delegates, mapkit, xcode6

I am trying to initial CLLocation with Latitude and Longitude. Then add it to a NSMutableArray called `trackPointArray`.

After doing this in a loop I have 18 `CLLocation` inside `currLocation`

```
CLLocation *currLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lastlang longitude:lastlong];
[trackPointArray addObject:currLocation];
```

After adding to that array I create a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

```
NSInteger numberOfSteps =trackPointArray.count;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
for(NSInteger index=0;index<numberOfSteps;index++)
{
    CLLocation *location = [trackPointArray objectAtIndex:index];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2 = location.coordinate;
    coordinates[index] = coordinate2;
}
```

Finally I call with this:

```
routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
[self.mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
```

And this function is `rendererForOverlay`:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if (![overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon *)overlay;
    MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:polygon];
    renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    return renderer;
}
```

1. I have debugged my project and it is not calling `rendererForOverlay`
2. And I have this line of code after `viewDidLoad()` self.mapView.delegate = self;
3. I have more than one point
4. And here is definition of my delegate in header file:

   UIViewController < MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, MKOverlay >

5.`MapView`=

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

6. I am trying this on simulator. And simulator is bringing the l

Here is definition of my variables:

```
NSMutableArray *trackPointArray;
MKMapRect routeRect;
MKPolylineView* routeLineView;
MKPolyline* routeLine;
```

Also I have used this older version but it is not called too:

```
-(MKOverlayView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *polylineview = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineview.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    polylineview.lineWidth = 5.0;
    return polylineview;
}
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks to Anna for her comment I think this would fix that issue:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *route = overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:route];
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        return routeRenderer;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

Comment: did you set the delegate? in viewDidLoad: `self.mapView.delegate = self;`

Comment: @Thedude Yes I did that. I have mentioned above in number 2.

Comment: At least a couple of problems: 1) In `initWithLatitude:lastlong longitude:lastlong`, it seems to be passing longitude value in the latitude parameter.  2) Code is creating and adding an MKPolyline but in rendererForOverlay, it returns nil if overlay is anything but MKPolygon (so it returns nil for MKPolyline).

Comment: Thansk dear @Anna .. Good spotting